# jQuery toggle class off when new element is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote a function that toggles a class. An element has a specific style and when it is selected the style changes, which works.  What I want it to do is have the styling on the selected element go back to the original when a new element is selected. Currently, it remains the new style when other elements are selected.

Is there a way to accomplish this with this function that I have written?

```
<script>
    $('.stylingchange').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('servicesiconchange');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Add your html with your code

Comment: maybe the dom didn't load at the time you set the event, try to put that code between $(function(){//your code here});

Comment: yes, please include the relevant html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select all instances of the class you want to remove and use `removeClass()`, then toggle the class on the element that was clicked.

```
$('.stylingchange').on('click', function(){
    $('.servicesiconchange').removeClass('servicesiconchange');
    $(this).toggleClass('servicesiconchange');
});
```

Or if you need to limit it to a class you could do this

```
$('.stylingchange').on('click', function(){
    $('.stylingchange.servicesiconchange').removeClass('servicesiconchange');
    $(this).toggleClass('servicesiconchange');
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it was the correct answer to your question. Thanks @Ana!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove class from each element who has .stylingchange class and then toggle from the current element.

```js
$('.stylingchange').click(function() {
             $('.stylingchange').removeClass('servicesiconchange');
            $(this).toggleClass('servicesiconchange');
        });
```

Check the following example which I created on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/1462crfs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.stylingchange').click(function(){
  $('.stylingchange.servicesiconchange').not(this).removeClass('.servicesiconchange');
  $(this).toggleClass('servicesiconchange');
})
```

First check for any elements with the toggle styling class that isn't the current item and remove the class, then toggle the class of the current item.